# Robot Rotation Angle and Turn Direction

Tags: c++, math

Working on Robot project and need to figure New Heading rotation amount and turn direction.
Input parameters are Current Heading and New Heading, Output values are Rotation amount in degrees and turn direct Port (Left) or Starboard (Right). Have solution below but it does not look very elegant. Any thoughts for more elegant solution?
Many thanks in advance imk

```
void AngleDiff( int RobotHeading , int NewHeading)
{
int SteeringAngle = RobotHeading - NewHeading;
char TurnDirection; // P = Port (Left) or S = Starboard (Right) 

if(  SteeringAngle > 180 )
 {
 SteeringAngle -= 360;
 SteeringAngle = abs( SteeringAngle );
 TurnDirection = 'S';
 return;
 }

if( SteeringAngle < -180 )
 {
 SteeringAngle += 360;
 TurnDirection = 'P';
 return;
 }

if( SteeringAngle < 0 )
 {
 SteeringAngle = abs( SteeringAngle );
 TurnDirection = 'S';
 }
else
 TurnDirection = 'P';
}
```

Comment: what do you consider as elegant / not elegant ? I think "elegant" = all my test pass and I can turn to other things.

Comment: Simple stuff like proper indentation and using `else if` instead of those early returns would help a lot.

Comment: hm... well, this function is not doing anything other than assigning to local variables, I have to disagree with what I said before, this is more elegant: `void AngleDiff( int , int){}`. Seriously, is this the code that works for you?

Comment: *"Output values are..."* Well, you are **not** outputting them, in any way. Is this an artifact of simplification of your actual code?

Comment: You may want to ask this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it is unclear what you are missing from your code. I do miss a way to return the result, but yes, that may be the result of oversimplification. I am certain one could squeeze the whole function into a single line of code, but that would certainly reduce the elegancy. The important thing is wether you can read and understand the code. A good test is to read it again after a week of not looking at it, if you still understand what it does, its fine

Comment: Many thanks for the comments,
I just hacked this together to test the results and yes better else if would be nice and yes it is not a complete function as it does not return results.  But it just doesn't look elegant even when tided up. Thought there would be a positive of oh: Do the math like this?

Comment: make correctness your main goal. THe function you show us here, cannot be the correct one, because it returns nothing. Write the function that is the correct one, then get a coffee, then turn to the next function. "elegant" is to not overthink stuff

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
if (SteeringAngle > 180)
{
    SteeringAngle -= 360;
}
else if (SteeringAngle < -180)
{
    SteeringAngle += 360;
}
TurnDirection = SteeringAngle < 0 ? 'S' : 'P';
SteeringAngle = abs(SteeringAngle);
```

Comment: Molbdnilo,
Many thanks, someone who understands what elegant means.
Have coded it up, given it some testing and now ready to add rest of required function to :-)
Many thanks imk
PS How do I add a thank you in this forum?

Comment: `if` -> `while` for that last piece of mojo.